# Does 13" Macbook Pro Retina have PowerNap?

Tags: macbook-pro, power-nap

Pretty straightforward question. I wonder if new 13" MBPRs come with power nap feature?

Comment: Does anything make you think it wouldn't?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, take a look at [this page](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/features-retina/).

It is about 13 and 15 inch MacBook Pro with retina display.
In the battery section they talk about the Power Nap.

You can also read the following articles:

- [Nbcnews](http://www.nbcnews.com/technology/gadgetbox/13-inch-macbook-pro-retina-display-unveiled-1C6632130)

> The new 13-inch model has 7 hours of battery life, Schiller said, and the new "Power Nap" feature lets the MacBook Pro with Retina display do software updates when it's plugged in, as well as back up the computer using Time Machine.

- [DailyFinance](http://www.dailyfinance.com/2012/10/23/apple-introduces-13-inch-macbook-pro-with-retina-d/)

> The 13-inch MacBook Pro battery delivers up to 7 hours of wireless productivity and can remain in standby for up to 30 days.** With the all new Power Nap feature in OS X® Mountain Lion, your MacBook Pro with Retina display stays up to date while it sleeps. Power Nap automatically refreshes Mail, Contacts, Calendar, Reminders, and Photo Stream, and when the notebook is plugged in, downloads software updates and backs up your Mac® using Time Machine®.